# Many or one foreground service in the app

Tags: android

Hello，There is three service in one app： A is foreground service，B is  a common service in the main app，C is a common service in the module is used by the app,  if i want to the c is not be killed, is the c also created as foreground service?

My another question:  if the app have a foreground service,other service is not be killed?

Answer (score 0):

Since services B and C are not foreground (and nothing that is foreground is bound to them), they can be killed at any moment.

If you want services B and C to stay alive, you'll have to bind to them. In your service A's onCreate call bindService(B) and bindService(C), and in A's onDestroy() call unbindService() for both

Answer (score 0):

As I know, when System low memory, service will be kill base on process priority. In your app, you already has foreground service so don't worry its will be alive same as foreground service without make C (foreground service). You can get more info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle)